# Pagination without affecting Audio streaming?

Tags: html5-audio, web-audio-api, flash, web-midi

If my web app is not single page app, how can I build an audio streaming with audio player which continue playing while paginating.

Comment: You need to convert it to a single page app... or use (i)frames.

Answer (score 0):

You can :

- use javascript for reloading other part of your web app (it's not only for single web app page)
- use system like symfony for rending part of the page with single controller without reload all. (Ok this solution is based on AJAX call)
- use iframe
- use iframe with other domain